# Postgres SQL or My SQL

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

Can anyone tell me which one is better for creating a small website, **PostgreSQL or MySQL......** I am using php for creating that website..

Answer (score 2):

If it's a really small website with small trafic, and you still need DB, you can use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) - it doesn't need database server.

Comment: There is no "mysqlite", it's SQLite. That has nothing to do with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL. Postgre SQL is more suitable for large-scaled websites (althought they both work on large-scale). Anyway, MySQL is faster.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. ok i wll move into mysql..

Comment: "MySQL is faster." Only when you use MyISAM and that turns off all reliability. In many other cases PostgreSQL is much faster. It all depends.

Comment: @Frank Heikens: don't take it too personal. The objective that I understood led me (and others) to assume there's no much need for the kind of reliability that I think you're questioning. I'm aware, more or less, of the problems of MySQL, and I agree with you, but in this case, there's just no big issue.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, MySQL is better for small php websites. 99% of hosting accouns support it and mysql extension for PHP is enabled also.
Postgre SQL is good for enterprise services.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. ok i wll move into mysql..

Comment: "MySQL is better." Since when? And what is you definition of "better"? MySQL is know for it's quirks, not for it's quality nor reliability.

Comment: @Frank better for small php website, because Vinoth13 asked about it.

Comment: For a small website, SQLite could be even better. It's included in PHP as well: "As of PHP 5 this extension is enabled by default, so simply do not disable it and it'll be available. " http://nl.php.net/sqlite